# Trouble with remaing time until the next time window in C++

Tags: c++, esp32

I am encountering a problem in writing a function. The purpose of this function is to calculate how many seconds are left until the next time window. The time windows are the times when it is allowed to perform a certain action, for example: I accept as allowed times all days from the 3th to the 5th of the year and also only from 6:00 am to 8:00 and from 18:00 to 20:00.

> Example: if the input timestamp is 1681146633 (Mon Apr 10 2023
> 17:10:33), as output I expect 2967. Because this number represents the
> number of seconds that are left until 18:00 that is the beginning of
> the time window.

My attempt is very simple. My method for storing the time windows is this: store the allowed months in pairs in the first row, with the first element of the pair representing the beginning of the interval and the second representing the end of the interval. Instead, in the second row I entered the allowed times always in pairs following the same pattern (a time with the .5 indicates the half-hour, e.g. 18.5 is equal to 18:30).

```
    float allowedTime[18][2] = {
         3,5,   3,   5,  6,  8, 6, 8,  9, 11,   9,  11,12,  2,  12, 2,
         6,8,18.5,20.5,5.5,7.5,19,21,6.5,8.5,17.5,19.5, 7,8.5,16.5,18,
    };
```

In the code I used the rtc class from [ESP32Time](https://github.com/fbiego/ESP32Time). The actual functions i wrote is:

```
int SecondsRemaingTo(ESP32Time &rtc,float allowedTime[][2]){
    int currentMonth = rtc.getMonth()+1, currentHour=rtc.getHour(true);
    int arrayx=18,arrayy=2;

    long int Epoch = rtc.getEpoch();
    //Temporany time struct where i will add time
    time_t unixTime = static_cast<time_t>(Epoch);
    struct tm* TempTime = localtime(&unixTime);
 
    int currentMon = TempTime->tm_mon + 1, curruntHour = TempTime->tm_hour, currentMin= TempTime->tm_min;
    int secondToNextWindow=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayx; i=i+2)
    {
        //Check month interval
        if(currentMon>=allowedTime[i][0] && currentMon<=allowedTime[i+1][0]){
            float minutes;
            //Check if i need to add 30 minutes
            if(currentMin>=30){
                minutes = 0.5;
            }else{
                minutes = 0;
            }
            float months = static_cast<float>(currentMon)+minutes;
            //Check Time interval
            if(months>=allowedTime[i][1] && months<=allowedTime[i+1][1]){
                return secondToNextWindow;
            }else{
                //Add 30 minutes until found a time window
                AddTime(1800, TempTime);
                secondToNextWindow+=1800;

            }
        }
    }
}

void AddTime(int seconds, tm* date) {
    if (date == NULL) return;
    date->tm_sec += seconds;
    mktime(date);
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question mark anywhere. What is your question?

Comment: @Dialecticus I added a blockquoute that should summarize my problem well.

Comment: Since you only fill 16 of 18 elements, allowing indexes `16`, `17` to be initialized by default to `0.0`, it looks like your tests `if(currentMon>=allowedTime[i][0]...` and `if(months>=allowedTime[i][1]...` test `true` when you don't want them to. Also enable compiler warnings and fix the `-Wmissing-braces` issue -- it will make your initialization much easier to read.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it

Comment: It is the last iteration where that comes into play. Add a test output (or step through in a debugger) and check if that is where things are going wrong. It is testing if `currentMon` and `months` are `>= 0.0` (which they are, causing you to take the true-branch of the `if` on the last iteration)